# Problem in magick package adding margings to an image and then annotating text

Tags: r, addition, margins

I want to read an image of 1500x1060px, add margins (aprox 3 cm at right) to it and in this margins plot a text. (It is in a shinny app that let the user change transparency).

If I do the text first and the margins after:

```
  image1 = jpeg::readJPEG(file.path(paste(input$map1,'.jpg', sep='')))  
  image1 = abind::abind(image1, image1[,,1]) # add an alpha channel
  image1[,,4] = input$trans1/100 # set alpha to semi-transparent
  image1<- image_read(image1)
    image1 <-     image_annotate(image1, "Generated with my.webpage", location = "+1550+1000", degrees = 270, size = 40, color = "black", strokecolor = NULL, boxcolor = NULL)

  png(outfile, width = 1500, height = 1060, units = 'px', res = 300)
  par(mar=c(0,0,0,3))
  plot.new()
  rasterImage(image1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  dev.off()
```

The text is annotated in a zone that does not exist yet so it doese not appear.

So im trying to use the image_annotate after the par(mar=()) but I don't now how to do it, as image_annotate has to be used with an object as first variable.

Comment: If you plot the image anyway, you can aölternativle write the annotation on the plot. The plot can be exported as raster image (jpeg, png) in low quality or vectorized text in high quality (pdf).

Comment: I don't really understand how to do it, and I'm sure it's simple but I'm getting mad here. 

It's being impossible for me to save the raster image within the plot.new and after the par function in a way that I can apply the image_read function needed to add text with image_annotated.

Answer (score 1):

As you presumably do not want to change the image to include rasterized text (poor quality), I would suggest to use the R buitlin function *mtext* to print the text on the margin, e.g.

```
img <- jpeg::readJPEG("image.jpeg")
plot.new()
rasterImage(img, rasterImage(img,0,0,1,1)
mtext("comment on image", side=1)
```

When opening a different device (pdf, png, or what else) before calling *plot.new()*, you can also save the annotated image to a file as shown in your example (do not forget to close the device with *dev.off()*, so that it is actually written).